# how to setup user authentication in django

Tags: django, authentication

I've been using Django to make this Web Service and I'm wondering how to make the user authentication work.  I heard that there's a built-in method to do it in Django, but I can't find it.  Does anyone have some experience in how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial on djangoproject.com is fairly good for explaining this.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/

Comment: I lookd through it and although it provides the functions for authenticating someone (which is useful) how can I integrate that into a page on the server?  How can I put two textboxes at the user and let them enter their authentication details and pass it to a function with those authentication functions.